# maxSize parameter of CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale not efficient

Tags: opencv

I'm performing pedestrian detection on a video stream using haar cascadeclassifiers and I am trying to optimize the code by reducing the scale range of detection thanks to parameters `minSize` and `maxSize` in the `detectMutliScale` function:

```
fullbodyCascade.detectMultiScale(image, found_pedestrian, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(20,60), Size(50,100));
```

It seems that the `minSize` parameter is the only one taken into account while objects with greater size than `maxSize` are still being detected.

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Ilou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The haar cascadeclassifier I am using is an old format file and the functions associated to this format do not seem to take maxSize into account. Therfore, I modified haar.cpp by adding :

```
    if( winSize.width > maxSize.width || winSize.height > maxSize.height ) break;
```

right before lig. 1202 :

```
    if( winSize.width < minSize.width || winSize.height < minSize.height )
    {
            if( findBiggestObject )
                break;
            continue;
    }
```

There was probably a more clever way to fix this (using flags...?)  but anyways,it works fine now.